# Display an older version of a CQ page

Tags: aem

For audit purposes I got the requirment to create a tool where the authors can look at older versions of a CQ page. I managed to get the available versions with the JCR VersionManager using the following code (used in a SlingServlet with cq:Page as the resourceType):

```
Session session = request.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(Session.class);
VersionManager vm = session.getWorkspace().getVersionManager();
VersionHistory versionHistory = vm.getVersionHistory(request.getResource().getPath());
VersionIterator vIt = versionHistory.getAllVersions();
while (vIt.hasNext()) {
    Version version = vIt.nextVersion();
    String no = version.getName();
    Calendar createdDate = version.getCreated();
    // do something with it
}
```

The path of the version points to e.g. `/jcr:system/jcr:versionStorage/d6/23/4f/d6234f36-3360-4024-bee2-411020ac63ae/1.0` where I can see a child node called `jcr:frozenNode` which seems to represent the jcr:content node of this specific version.

How can I tell CQ to render the page in this version? I would expect an url with some parameter or selector, but I didn't find any documentation. I tried to reverse engineer it with the Timewarp, but there the URL seems to be still the original and the magic is hidden somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I was also in contact with adobe support regarding this, and beside the timewarp there seems to be no built in feature to achieve this. Nevertheless I did some experimenting and found a feasible workaround. Though it might not be easy for a complex layout with many fixed components in the template, luckily on our case we mainly have a parsys.
So my solution is the following: I load the older version through two selectors in the url:

1. I called it "versionhistory" which is used to take another rendering script called `versionhistory.jsp` on the page component.
2. contains the actual version/node name (replacing "." with "_" to not add more selectors

In my `versionhistory.jsp` I just add the correct path for the parsys component (taking the example path from the question), and include the same layout elements as in the default script e.g. `page.jsp`:

```
<cq:include path="/jcr:system/jcr:versionStorage/d6/23/4f/d6234f36-3360-4024-bee2-411020ac63ae/1.0/jcr:frozenNode/par" resourceType="foundation/components/parsys" />
```